# Translating profession from two records written in Kurrentshrift

Tags: germany, occupation, kurrent

I'm struggling to identify these characters in two records for the same person, recorded one year apart. The documents are from around 1900 and written in Kurrent, and I've tried using both a [Kurrent letter guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent#/media/File:Deutsche_Kurrentschrift.svg) and several German profession lists.

The first one is on the individual's death:
[image: screenshot profession one]

The second is one year prior:
[image: screenshot profession two]

I'm reasonably certain these are the same person.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The occupation is 
Möbelpolierer 
[furniture polisher]

Probably different tasks depending on the employer: at a residence, a furniture store or a factory

Comment: Thank you! I definitely wouldn't have got there on my own.